# How do I loop through grid properly?

Tags: php, loops, laravel-5, grid

I'm currently working on a photo gallery index.

How can I make it so that my loop iterates all 4 columns and then proceeds making a new row?

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">

    @foreach($photoGalleries as $photoGallery)

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="{{ url('/photogalleries/' . $photoGallery->id) }}">
                <img class="img-fluid" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;" src="/images/{{ $photoGallery->cover_image }}">
            </a>
            <h3>{{ $photoGallery->name }}</h3>
        </div>

    @endforeach 

</div>
```

Now as you can imagine, it'll appear like this:

[image]

**Alternative solution:**

Add margin-top after the `col-md-3` attribute, like so:

```
<div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top: 20px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Can't understand your question, your code should generate a layout similar to your image

Comment: I am currently looping (iterating) before the ```col-md-3```tag as seen in the picture (and code) above. Now, there's no break after the 4th picture. I want to iterate 4 columns, *new row* (for the break) and repeat that process. Adding my loop before the row would just make a row every time without filling the 4 columns with photos.

Comment: Well according to my knowledge you have two options. 1st: You can chunk the collection for collections of collections with 4 items and iterate using two foreach loops. 2nd: Check remainder 0 when dividing key + 1 by 4 and add a div.row

Comment: Uhh, "chunk the collection for collections of collections with 4 items" kind of confused me. Can you post an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$collectionOne = $photoGalleries->chunk(4);


@foreach($collectionOne as $collectionTwo) 
    <div class "row" >
        @foreach($collectionTwo as $photoGallery) 
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="">...... </a>
            </div>
        @endforeah
    </div>
@endforeach
```